# How to pull the data context from a view in Meteor using Blaze.getData()

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have a select input in one of my Meteor templates which has three pieces of data associated with each select option. I am trying to send all three pieces of data (as an object) to a new template that is rendered via the Blaze API on the 'change' event triggered after the user's selection. I am under the impression I can use the Blaze.getData method to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I was wondering if anyone has any experience using this method and might be able to help me troubleshoot.

I have a MeteorPad set up with an example of what I am trying to do here:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/69XGm5nWPutg8an7T/Select%20Item

Also, here is the relevant 'change' event code:

```
Template.selectItem.events({
  'change .select_item': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var view = Blaze.getView(event.target);
    console.log(view); // me debugging
    var item = Blaze.getData(view);
    console.log(item); // me debugging
    Blaze.renderWithData(Template.selectedResults, item, document.getElementById('results'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template in question, *selectItem*, has no data context, which is why this isn't working.  Blaze is rendering `{{#each items}}` by looking up the appropriate helper function, but this *isn't* part of the data context of the template, so you can't retrieve it from the event handler.

The easiest way to resolve this is by setting the data context of the *selectItem* template when it's called from the surrounding body template, like this:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return Items.find(); //or Items, or whatever
  }
});
```

and

```
<body>
  <h1>Select an item</h1>
    {{> selectItem items=items}}
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

That way, the data context you retrieve in the event handler will contain `items`, although what you then do with it is up to you.

If you wanted to continue doing things the way you are, the sensible thing to do would just be to pick up the *items* array directly as it's in the JS scope of your event handler.  If you really wanted to do things via the helper function, you could try:

`Template.selectItem.__helpers[' items'].apply(Template.instance())`

However, this would be using private methods and really isn't to be recommended. Plus, it would be rerunning the helper anyway, and not really returning the results of the same run, which appears to be what you're after.

Comment: So this was the source of the issue...and a few other things. In my meteor code, the items array comes from a separate source, so the scope suggestion didn't really work. However, explicitly setting the data context did fix the issue. I also ended up putting the <option></option> nodes in a separate template, which meant I needed to grab the selected node using jquery. I had some minor issues with this, but got it figured out. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the working code is now on the meteorpad example for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You need `Blaze.getData` to get data from an element, otherwise :

```
 Template.selectItem.events({
    'change .select_item': function(event,template) {
     this//->data from event.target
     template.data //->data from current template
     Blaze.getData(event.target)//data from event.target

})
```

Edit :

I didn't look at your Meteorpad sorry.

Your event is binded to your `select`. When it's triggered you will get the `select` as target in `event.target` and you will get `price` in `event.target.value`.

You could use this :

1.build your data in a collection

```
var Items = new Mongo.Collection(null)
[
  {
    price: 500,
    name: 'apple',
    unit: 'bushel'
  },
  {
    price: 1000,
    name: 'bananas',
    unit: 'kilo'
  },
  {
    price: 2000,
    name: 'cake',
    unit: 'slice'
  }
].forEach(function(o){
    Items.insert(o)
});
```

2.Iterate over the items and give `_id` as the value

```
Template.selectItem.helpers({
  items: function()
  {
    return Items.find()
  }
});


<template name="selectItem">
  <select name="item" class="select_item" style="width: 50%;">
    <option></option>
    {{#each items}}
      <option value="{{this._id}}">{{this.name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

3.Use `Items.findOne(event.target.value)` to get the selected Item

```
Template.selectItem.events({
    'change .select_item': function(event,template) {
     Blaze.renderWithData(Template.selectedResults,   Items.findOne(event.target.value), document.getElementById('results'));

})
```

Comment: The issue I'm having is for the three values you posted (this, template.data, and Blaze.getData(event.target)), they are all returning either null or an empty object. Is it possible Blaze doesn't play nicely with select boxes?

Comment: I corrected my answer. You won't get the selected data this way.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I left out some important info by simplifying to provide an example. The data I'm using for the options in my select element are actually from an embedded array in another collection (a pricing document), so I have to access the data as an array. Theoretically, I could do a Collection.find({name:name, price: price}); in the event handler, but I like the idea of passing the original data, as it reduces the chance of an unforeseen error. The other option is using a Session variable...aside from that, I was wanting to understand why this code wasn't working right.